# Resultative adjectives

Tags: adjectives, resultative

> Couples shouldn’t go to bed offended against each other.

> Larry washed the car clean.

> He Printed the photo very small.

Today I tried to understand “resultative adjectives”, but they confused me. As far as I can see from some dictionaries, such as the Oxford Learners Dictionary, we can’t use some verbs with adjectives, but in the sentences above adjectives modify the nouns. I couldn’t understand how printing the photo smaller is possible. Would it be better and more grammatical if I say the sentences below, or are these structures totally grammatical? If they are grammatical, can someone please explain resultative adjectives?

> Couples shouldn’t go to bed in a state in which they are offended against each other.

> Larry washed the car in such a way that it is clean.

> He printed the photo as very small.

Comment: Couples shouldn't go to bed (being) offended at each other. Larry washed the car (so that it became) clean. I don't think the third sentence is correct -- the photo doesn't exist except as a printed object, because that's what a photo is! I'd say "He printed a tiny photo."

Comment: Couples shouldn't go to bed angry. [at each other]. The boy licked his plate clean. I see where you are going with this. I had an entire analysis of this structure on ELU but I can't find it.

Comment: "He printed the photo _in a very small format_."

Comment: Ok, I found my analysis of this, which, doesn't really have a name though it can be described: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328758/how-to-analyse-shot-dead/328790#328790